# Blur an input field in testcafe

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, blur, testcafe

I'm attempting to blur an input field in testcafe but can't seem to find out how.

I can use `t.pressKey( "tab" );` although I don't feel this way is very good.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: [`HTMLElement.blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe is intended to emulate real-user behavior. So, I think that pressing `tab` isn't a bad workaround to make the element lose its focus.

If you do not want to emulate key pressing, you can emulate a click on some other element, which will lead to `blur` on your input.

Of course, you can call the `blur` method of the input element using the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism, but it will require some extra coding.

Comment: Thanks Alex - makes perfect sense. I have gone with clicking another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another element to take the focus away from the current element.

```
<input id="main">
...
<input id="grabber">

document.getElementById('grabber').focus();
```